# Updating MySQL table with a concatenation

Tags: mysql, csv, concatenation

I have a MySQL table(TMP) which countains lots of products which have a "name" field, that I want to update with some others column(Concatenation of two columns) from another table(CSV).

My CSV table countains the name of a product and an associated number that I want to concatenate as the new name of the same product in my TMP table. the TMP name and the CSV table are the same for all the products, and I want, at the end, that the TMP name is the CSV name + the CSV number.

I tried something like

```
UPDATE tmp.TMP 
SET name = (SELECT CONCAT(tmp.CSV.nom," ",tmp.CSV.cb) 
            FROM tmp.CSV, tmp.TMP
            where CSV.nom = TMP.name
            and accountId=1297
            )
where accountId = 1297
```

But it, obviously, doesn't work.

Comment: why not use JOIN and UPDATE and in which table `accountId` belongs ?

Comment: accountId belongs to TMP, sorry to forget that. And I don't know how to use JOIN, I am a beginner in mySQL.

Comment: You cannot use a `SELECT` statement inside an `UPDATE` query if you `SELECT` the same table. Otherwise MySQL would `UPDATE` the table and the `SELECT` result could change according to the `UPDATE` and create unexpected results.

Comment: @Thibault do you have any solutions for this so?

Comment: before giving solution what is the size of `name` field in TMP table ?

Comment: the maximum I can see in the table is 50 and with the accountID 1297 48. I don't know exactly the maximum length.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tmp.CSV AS c, tmp.TMP AS t
SET t.name = CONCAT(c.nom, " ", c.cb) 
WHERE c.nom = t.name
    AND t.accountId = 1297;
```

Comment: It doesn't like the FROM line, it says me an SQL syntax error.

Comment: @Valinor77 - Yeah, that was left over from your query. I removed it already... try again.

Comment: This gives me a warning : "0 row(s) affected, 3 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'name' at row 173 1265 Data truncated for column 'name' at row 288 1265 Data truncated for column 'name' at row 909 Rows matched: 3 Changed: 0 Warnings: 3" and some fields have been updated and some not.

Comment: @Valinor77 Could you, please, post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp.TMP;`? Apparently, it has some interfering constraints, and the tmp.TMP.name field is too short.

Comment: # Table, Create Table
'TMP', 'CREATE TABLE `TMP` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `accountId` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL)  I deleted some fields which are useless for this request.

Comment: Increase the size of your name column so it can store the data you want it to store.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE TMP ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(255);` - then the update will work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `SELECT` statement inside an `UPDATE` query if you `SELECT` the same table.

Otherwise MySQL would `UPDATE` the table and the `SELECT` result could change according to the `UPDATE` and create unexpected results.

If your goal is to make simple requests, you can use Steven Moseley query, which is fine for your problem. But if you need to do more complex queries you can use a temporary table :

- Create a temporary `mytable` with the `SELECT`'s results
- make an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN` to update your `TMP` table using the `mytable` content.

Here is how you can do :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
SELECT CONCAT(tmp.CSV.nom," ",tmp.CSV.cb) as name, TMP.accountId 
FROM tmp.CSV, tmp.TMP
where CSV.nom = TMP.name
and TMP.accountId=1297;
```

Then run your query base on `mytable`

```
UPDATE tmp.TMP, tmp.mytable
SET TMP.name = mytable.name
WHERE TMP.accountId=mytable.accountId
AND accountId=1297;
```

Then :

```
DROP mytable;
```

Comment: Two things : mytable doesnt have an accountId(and CSV either but I replace with TMP.accountId) and mytable has one column which countains the concatenate so... DId i forget something ?

Comment: By the way, i forgot to say that, but maybe you would like to know that every line in TMP has an id, the accountId is a foreign key for the client.